# Subscription The item you requested is not available for purchase

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm doing a game with Unity3D and I will publish it in Android's Google Play Store. This game is almost finished, not finished yet because of this error.

Let me explain it, in my game there are little IAP Purchases, to buy coins, power ups and that kind of stuff. The real problem comes here, I have 3 different types of subscriptions, one is called VIP, the other is Gold VIP and the last one is Diamond VIP (very creative, right?).

Well, all was doing pretty fine until I tried to purchase that subscription pressing a button with code that will buy this subscription (Not the Unity's default codeless button, one i made by myself), the following error message from a Play Store popup appears:

> The item you requested is not available for purchase.

This is really weird, because If I want to purchase a consumable item, all works fine. This are the things I have:

- All subscriptions are activated in the Google Play Console
- The subscription IDS match in code with the Google Play Developer Console ones
- The app is published as an Alpha and I'm signed in the Play Store with the beta account
- I downloaded the APK file from Play Store

Here's my code:

```
//IAP Manager Code
//This Is the only thing I've modified, the other code it's just the Unity IAP Code that it's on their webpage

    public void BuyVIP()
    {
            BuyProductID(ProductVIP);
    }


public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
        {
         if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definitionProductVIP, StringComparison.Ordinal))
          {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("VIP", 1);
            Success();
          }
         }

//VIP Button Code

 private Button B;
    void Start()
    {
        B = GetComponent<Button>();
        B.onClick.AddListener(Clicker);
    }
    void Clicker()
    {
        IAPManager.Instance.BuyVIP();
    }
```

Comment: Does Unity throws an expection or so while testing it on your devce?

Comment: @DaniTorres Yes, I tested both, in my computer and in my device. In my device doesn't work, but in my computer the console doesn't throw any kind of warning or exception, it just works perfectly...